# New Address Book App-How to Import Contacts From Existing Address Book to my App?

Tags: iphone, ios5, addressbook

I am working on an app for a new address book.  Is there code existing to make a button to import your contact (from existing address book) into my app?  And add *67 to these new contacts if possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on how to import contacts from the address book.

[**ABAddressBook Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

### Here is an example

```
CFStringRef phone,phoneLabel;
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSMutableDictionary *myPhoneDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneMulti)];
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneMulti); i++) { 
    phoneLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneMulti, i));
    phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneMulti, i); 
    [myPhoneDict setObject:(NSString*)phone forKey:(NSString*)phoneLabel];
    CFRelease(phone);
    CFRelease(phoneLabel);
} 
if ( [myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"mobile"] != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Cell Phone: %@",[myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"mobile"]);
} 

else if ( [myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"home"] != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Home Phone: %@",[myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"home"]);
} 

else if ( [myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"work"] != nil) {
    NSLog@"Work Phone: %@",[myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"work"]);
}
```

You can then take whatever number you are looking for and prepend  your *67 number to it, then save that new string.

Comment: The URL is for the OS X classes; are they similar enough or even identical to the iOS variants?